# last_insert_id() in sqlite CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, sqlite

can anyone see the fatal flaw in this code or sugest an alternative?

```
int task_id = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid();", null).toInt(1);
```

At this line it throws the following exception:

```
 android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

EDIT:
figured it out, the null is the problem.

The correct code is:

```
 int task_id = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid();", new String[] {} ).getInt(0);
```

Comment: It seems to crash? Or it does crash? What do you mean by crask? An exception?  What error message?

Comment: i get android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1